# JLNINK(SWD)+IAR can not debug stm32: communication error

Tags: stm32, swd

guys. I am using J-link with SWD interface to debug my STM32F103VCT6 in IAR. I can enter download and debug mode but I can not use "step over" or "stop" function. Once I use one of them I will get communication error

[image: communication error]

and if I click "NO" , another dialog window will appear

[image]

I have tested STM32F103VCT6 with J-link commander, I can use basic command to find core:
[image]

I have already added a reset circuit( 5.6K + 30pF). can anybody give some suggestions？

Comment: Hopefully your problem isn't what I had happen with my J-Link several years ago. Several boards that it had worked with previously started doing exactly the same and later it died altogether and wouldn't program anything. Has yours worked before on other boards or is the first project using it?

Comment: yeah,I have tested my Jlink with another board and it works..